# Where to put *.lang syntax highlighting files for gedit in Windows

Tags: windows-7, gedit

I'm trying to add coffeescript syntax highlighting to gedit in Windows, but I can't work out where to put the `*.lang` file.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/wavded/gedit-coffeescript), but the path `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs` doesn't seem to apply to Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to look here:

```
C:\Program Files\gedit\share\gtksourceview-2.0\language-specs\
```

Comment: @Acorn If you click the green checkmark next to my answer to mark it as accepted. This will show the community that the question was answered.

Comment: I had to wait for a time limit to expire before I could choose it as the answer :)

Comment: @evan.bovie At least in Gedit 3.20.1, styles and plugins can be put in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gedit\styles` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gedit\plugins` respectively. I'm looking for a similar path in the user's home directory where language files can be put. I have tried `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gedit\share\gtksourceview-3.0\language-specs` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\Program Files\gedit\share\gtksourceview-3.0\language-specs` but the language files are not read by Gedit.

Comment: @evan.bovie Found the answer by using ProcMon.

Answer (score 0):

For a local installation you should be able to put the language files in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gtksourceview-2.0\language-specs` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gtksourceview-3.0\language-specs` depending on the version of Gedit.

Using Gedit 3.20.1 I found the result with ProcMon (Process Monitor) in Windows by filtering on paths containing `language-specs` (with ProcMon you can see what files and folders an application tries to open).